# My Code is not rendering @scripts section in the _Layout in Asp.Net Mvc and when even i run the it give failed popup

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

//  This is my controller class which iam using iam making a time table in Asp.Net mvc .... My View against my contrller every time i run it give a popup of failed iam not exactly sure but i think that the issue with my _Layout or somwthing else mabye its the issue that its not loading the jquery in Asp.net Mvc 5

```
public class TutorController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            using (TutorHubContext dc = new TutorHubContext())
            {
                var events = dc.TimeTables.ToList();
                return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
        }
    }



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <div id="calender"></div>


    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
    @section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Tutor/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            eventID: v.EventID,
                            title: v.Subject,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.Start),
                            end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                            color: v.ThemeColor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                        });
                    })
                    GenerateCalender(event)
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: '#378006',
                    events: events
                })
            }
        })

    </script>
  }
</body>
</html>
```

// plz anybody help me

Comment: I am using visual studio 2017

Comment: You have not included `jquery-{version}.js` (which need to be the first script) -

Comment: If you're getting an `alert('failed');` then clearly this code *is* being included in the page and *is* executing.  As for *why* the AJAX call is failing, you're going to have to examine the actual error.  `alert('failed');` doesn't really tell you much, does it?  What's in the `error` variable in that function?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, in the network tab what is the response from the server?  When you debug your server-side code, where does it fail?

Comment: where do i have to mention the version of jquery-{version}.js in which class or file and i my controoler is working fine but when after that i get the alert failed its actully picking the _Layout but after that it there appeears a messag of failed

Comment: This is my _Layout.cshtml

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 
</head>


<body>
      @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

Comment: plzz help me ia really stuck and iam doing my final yaer project and a module of my project

Comment: @AamirNaeem: Use your browser's debugging tools.  You're getting an `alert('failed');` because *you wrote that exact line of code*.  So the code is doing *exactly what you told it to do*.  It's doing this in response to an error from the server in the AJAX request.  So you need to find out *what that error is*.  In your browser's debugging tools, check the network tab.  Examine the *actual response* from the server in the AJAX call.  It's probably telling you exactly what the problem is, you're just ignoring it.

Comment: n browser its giving  GET GETeVENTS 500 Internal SEVER ERROR

Comment: In browser its giving Error GetEvents  500  xhr jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 its giving a red line on that but what kind of error is that @David

Comment: @AamirNaeem You need to go track down that error on the server side.  Resolving that will allow you to get further on your client side.

Comment: @AamirNaeem: That means there's an error server-side.  Does the response body show the error message?  You can turn on remote error messages in your web.config.  You can also attach your debugger to your application and step through the controller action to see what's failing.

Comment: @AamirNaeem If you're using Chrome, you can click on the error line to get a details view.  Click Preview tab to see further information.

Comment: See all these comments asking for clarification? That's an indicator that your question is *bad*. Please revise it and clarify exactly what your problem is. Take the time and effort with writing your question that you would expect one of us to take in answering it. Right now, that's not much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something looks a little suspicious here.  You say that's your view; but that looks like it contains a complete `<html> ... </html>` document.

Your _Layout.cshtml should contain the outer `<html> ... </html>` bits, and inside that file you need to call to `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`.

Later in your view you should have the `@section Scripts { ... }` just as you do currently.

To be clear, I would make my _Layout.cshtml contain the following (note, per @Stephen Muecke's advice, I added jQuery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- common css here -->

    <!-- page specific css here -->
    @RenderSection("Css", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <!-- common scripts here -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- page specific scripts here -->
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Then my {View}.cshtml would contain:

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="calender"></div>

@section Css {
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
}
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Tutor/GetEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        eventID: v.EventID,
                        title: v.Subject,
                        description: v.Description,
                        start: moment(v.Start),
                        end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                        color: v.ThemeColor,
                        allDay: v.IsFullDay
                    });
                })
                GenerateCalender(event)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        })

        function GenerateCalender(events) {
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 400,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: events
            })
        }
    })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: While this is certainly better, browsers can be pretty forgiving about including a complete HTML document inside of an HTML document.  The OP reports that the `alert('failed');` line is successfully executing, which pretty conclusively demonstrates that the client-side code is at least successfully executing.